# Is "in the interim" synonym of "in the meantime"

Tags: phrase-usage, phrases

The context is to wish someone a good recovery after knowing they have been unwell and delayed the project timeline. After assuring them not to worry about work for now, is it okay to say

> In the interim, more importantly, do rest well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They both mean the same. For an informal note, I would choose "in the meantime", or just an adverb, "meanwhile" :

> Meanwhile, more importantly, just rest well.

Comment: Is a lightbulb moment! The word *Meanwhile* never crossed my mind and it fits just right after you mentioned it!